# Activate Gutenberg in category-descriptions

Tags: categories, block-editor

I'm trying to convert my sites to Gutenberg. I like it!!

But how do I make it possible to make category-descriptions using the new editor?

[image: Gutenberg editor in category description]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible at the moment, Gutenberg is a post editor that relies on REST API endpoints, it's not an arbitrary content area editor as TinyMCE is.

Given some modification though it could be made to work with a custom data model and be a replacement, but it's not a trivial task, and what's involved is in flux. It would be best to ask over on the Gutenberg GitHub issue tracker

Comment: There is at least one ticket: [#12511](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12511), where the team said this is something for phase 2. Tom, given your work and your talk at WCEU, do you happen to have some experience in this now?

Comment: Any new updates on this?

Comment: this is the closest to an answer one can expect https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/, there's no direct equivalent of the classic `wp_editor` tinyMCE instance that can be dropped in. I've tried to do similar things to approximate it, the answer tends to be JS based. More often than not a block based world means that you would never need to consider the need for this in the first place as the paradigm has changed

Answer (score 0):

I had been able to do this, more or less, by:

1. Creating the content and format I wanted within the Guttenberg editor in a post
2. Switching from the visual to the code editor
3. Copying the code across into the "Archive Intro Text" of the category using the text - not visual - editor

The update to WP 5.7 from 5.6.2 has however messed up the formating

As you can see I'm in no way competent to write code and have created for myself a lovely dead end with my workaround, but I thought the knowledge might be useful, and I for one would be very grateful if this functionality was included in future releases.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to WPSE. This site consists almost wholly of people who developed with WordPress. For future requests, bug supports, and general support, you might be better off with the [WordPress support site](https://wordpress.org/support/) perhaps using the tag "Feature request" in the forums there. However, if you want help updating your hack, consider rewording your question to explain the output you now get and what you have tried to fix it so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom post type and connect it to the term via a custom term_meta where you store the custom_post_type ID
ie: with acf plugin
display this post_content where you want with

```
$_your_meta_value=get_term_meta($term_id, _description, 1);
echo apply_filter('the_content',get_the_content(null,false,$_your_meta_value));
```